# How to mock MongoClient using unittest.mock.patch ("TypeError: 'MongoClient' object is not callable")

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to replace my `MongoClient` with the `mongomock` version, using `unittest.mock.patch`, but for some reason, it breaks. Here is my example code, ran with `pytest -sv` (As can be seen, the object is obviously callable, so I really don't get the error):

```
import pymongo
import mongomock
import unittest


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient()
        

def test_mock():
    with unittest.mock.patch('pymongo.MongoClient', new_callable=mongomock.MongoClient):
        assert isinstance(A().client, mongomock.MongoClient)


def test_sanity():
    assert isinstance(A().client, pymongo.MongoClient)
    assert hasattr(mongomock.MongoClient, '__call__')
```

This is the failure:

```
====================================================================================================================================== FAILURES =======================================================================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_mock ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_mock():
        with unittest.mock.patch('pymongo.MongoClient', new_callable=mongomock.MongoClient):
>           assert isinstance(A().client, mongomock.MongoClient)

test_mock_mongo.py:13:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <test_mock_mongo.A object at 0x7f74013c7ac0>

    def __init__(self):
>       self.client = pymongo.MongoClient()
E       TypeError: 'MongoClient' object is not callable

test_mock_mongo.py:8: TypeError
=============================================================================================================================== short test summary info ===============================================================================================================================
FAILED test_mock_mongo.py::test_mock - TypeError: 'MongoClient' object is not callable
============================================================================================================================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.17s =============================================================================================================================
```

---

**EDIT**: I think I had to patch before the import. I've revised the code, but still failed:

```
import mongomock
```

import unittest

with unittest.mock.patch('pymongo.MongoClient', new_callable=mongomock.MongoClient) as mocked_mongo:
import pymongo
class A:
def **init**(self):
self.client = pymongo.MongoClient()

```
def test_mock():
        assert isinstance(A().client, mongomock.MongoClient)


def test_sanity():
    assert isinstance(A().client, pymongo.MongoClient)
    assert hasattr(mongomock.MongoClient, '__call__')
```

New failure: the object is still pymongo.MongoClient...

*python 3.8.0*

*pytest 6.0.2*

*pymongo==3.11.0*

*mongomock==3.21.0*

Comment: I believe you're supposed to mock your instance, and not the class definition, so look for mocking A.client instead of the MongoClient

Comment: Usage of `new_callable` is wrong here: `patch('pymongo.MongoClient', MongoClient)` should already suffice.